# Update the outdated sponsored icons for Google Cloud Products

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags, sponsored-tags

Google recently [updated the logos](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.de/2013/12/an-ode-to-sharkon.html) for the cloud products so I think it would be nice to update them here as well.

The outdated icons:

- [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-app-engine/info)
- [google-cloud-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-storage/info)
- [google-bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-bigquery/info)
- [google-compute-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-compute-engine/info)

The ones without icons:

- [google-cloud-datastore](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-datastore/info)
- [google-cloud-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-cloud-sql/info)

I know that the ones without icons need some "action" from Google, but maybe they will arrange it :)

Comment: It's probably all up to google as they had to pay to get those logos there in the first place.

Comment: @Amicable updating the logos and getting the new ones are two different things.. I'm part of the Google Developers Expert program so I already informed some people from Google that could do something about it.. I just wanted to have it here as an issue as well.

Comment: If you already informed the necessary people at Google, why raise here a question? I mean, they obviously should care, you told them, and there's not much we or SE can do here (I'd be surprised if SE is allowed to swap out icons without order from the client).

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby well maybe to post the logos as answers.. or I don't know how it works with sponsored links..

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Plus this question is also for the admins of SE, because maybe for updating the icons we could completely skip talking to the client..

Comment: @Lipis: Given that they *paid* for showing these icons, I think clients would not be happy if SE simply swapped them, just because there seem to be newer ones available. Especially at big companies the marketing team has a plan on what to do and when to do it, I'm not sure if they'd be happy. I mean, I see where you're coming from, but I fail to see how this needs to be here on Meta too when you already informed the necessary people at Google.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby Yes maybe you're right about swapping without permission, but I wanted to have it here for the links to the actual tags and resolve it here.. that's why the meta was all about.. no?! Am I missing something..?

Comment: @Lipis: I see it like a question about the content of ads, it does not belong here but needs to be directed at the appropriate...advertised company. F.e. if an ad on Stack Overflow contains outdated information, it will not do much if you raise it here, the company should be informed that they forgot to update the ads on Stack Exchange. Of course you can post it here, but that will ping the mods, they will ping the ad-people, they will ping that company. Of course, if there's a *real* problem with the ad, like it's obscene, NSFW or scam, then it would be good to come here and state that.

Comment: Actually, we greatly appreciate the heads-up. We have a small ad staff. Stevve and I monitor the "advertising" and "sponsored-tags" tags regularly as the community often finds issues that we don't find in our testing phase. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent suggestion, @Lipis! We've reached out to the client with your suggestion and will update here with relevant updates.

---

All updated except for 
[google-cloud-datastore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-datastore) 
[google-cloud-sql](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-sql)

...because they don't currently own those.

BUT LOOK HOW PRETTY THOSE NEW LOGOS ARE!

:-)

Comment: Everyone's changing logo... Firefox, Google... who's next? ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Stack Exchange. And Stack Overflow. Just kidding ;)

Comment: @Oded that won't be a bad idea in my opinion... nothing wrong with current logo but would also be cool to change at some point. :)

Comment: now when will you start supporting HDPI screens...? Especially the small icons looks very very ugly..